# Cordova plugin to import videos

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, gallery

I want to import videos (mp4) on ipad application. There are few plugins already available and we used one of them. But it converts the video to a particular format and we have to then reconvert it to mp4. Considering the videos will be about 2 gb in size, it takes a lot of time in double conversion. It creates a very bad user experience as this is the first step in the app.

Is there a plugin available already which can help us to import the video without going through the conversation process. Even better if we can choose if we wish to convert the video or want to skip it.

Comment: import from where? internet or local files? Also provide the plugin link that you have used before.

Comment: Want to import from gallery on ipad. We are using following plugin to import data. It works, but it takes lot of time in compressing the video and it converts mp4 files to .mov files. We then have to reconvert the .mov files to .mp4, so we can play it in html5 player. Reconverting takes even longer. Is there a way to bypass the conversion/compression process in the plugin we use? or is there any other plugin available which allows us to do that: -      https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#select-a-file-from-the-picture-library-

Comment: github link for the plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Answer (score 0):

[cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) is for capturing from Device Camera.

There are plugins available to play video directly from the URL or local files-

1. Plugin - [cordova-plugin-videoplayer](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer)

   A Codova plugin that simply allows you to immediately play a video in fullscreen mode.

   Example -

   ```
   VideoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4");
   VideoPlayer.play(
       "file:///android_asset/www/movie.mp4",
       {
           volume: 0.5,
           scalingMode: VideoPlayer.SCALING_MODE.SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING
       },
       function () {
           console.log("video completed");
       },
       function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
   );
   ```
2. Plugin - [VideoPlayer](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer)

   The video player allows you to display videos from your PhoneGap applications.
   Refer [Adding the Plugin to your project](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer#adding-the-plugin-to-your-project) and [Usage](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer#using-the-plugin).